# DotNetBrowser calling a JS function and returning a value from C#

Tags: javascript, vb.net, function, return-value, dotnetbrowser

I see the option where you can initiate the function call in .NET and return a value, but I don't see an option where you are able to initiate a function call in javascript calling a .NET function and then return a value to javascript, similar to what would happen if I was using ASP.NET or hitting a Web API.

So basically here is what I am doing.  I have a modal that pops up when the user clicks to save game.  They enter the name of the Save Game file, click OK and it calls a .NET function to check the DB to see if it's a duplicate save game file or not.  If it is, it should return "Error! Duplicate file name! Please choose a unique file name."  If it is unique it saves the information to a DB and returns a "Successfully saved game!" message, waits 2 seconds and then redirects to the main dashboard page.

I have everything working fine up until the point .NET is supposed to return the value.  Currently the modal window just sits there and nothing returns to JS.

I have it set up like I normally would through calling the .Net function and using .then(function (response) to get the response value, but it is coming back as undefined.

I'm sure there has to be a way to do this, I just don't see how in the documentation as that only shows how to do it when initiating the function call from .NET...

EDIT:  OMG...I just realized this was such a dumb question...I'm already doing that returning lookups from the database...the answer was to set it equal to a variable instead of trying to chain the function onto the end.

THIS:

```
var value = window.CRUD.Save(fileName, model);
if(value === "Duplicate!") ....
```

INSTEAD OF:

```
    window.CRUD.Save(fileName, model).then(function(response) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The article by the following link explains how to call .NET from JavaScript:
https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000109869-calling-net-from-javascript

Thank you for adding your answer  to the question as an update.